# React: client-side routing with react-router on gh pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages, parceljs

I am having the problem discussed in the React Create App docs about how routers that use the HTML5 pushState history API will fail on static file servers without configuring it to serve index.html everytime. How can I fix this problem while using github pages? Also I'm not using the Create React App or react-scripts

I have tried adding a basename to the BrowserRouter component

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
```

Much better explanation of the problem here:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `react-router-dom` with GitHub pages, you'll need to use [`HashRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) instead of `BrowserRouter`. It uses the `#` fragment of the URL to keep the route, circumventing the lack of support for `pushState` on GH pages.

(There *are* some awkward ways to make `pushState` for GitHub pages, but I don't personally recommend them. [Here's a guide for that](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages))

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of hashRouter but I was told it was bad practice to use in production. Also I've seen some decent ways to deploy BrowserRouter to other static hoster like Azure and Heroku but I want to use github. I would love to hear ways of getting BrowserRouter to work on gh-pages. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a link to the guide in my answer, if you want to try it. Sure, HashRouter is a compromise. But since GH pages does _not_ technically support client-side routes, any solution would be a hack, and not actually recommended for production / long-term use.

Comment: You were right, I don't want to use that 404 hack, that is definitely awkward. I will go with HashRouter instead. Thanks for the time!

Comment: No problem, my pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

```
import { HashRouter, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(

      <HashRouter>
        <App />
      </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I resolve this problem use HashRouter.