# React project with react-router-dom problem with routes on gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, react-router-dom, router

I have small react project with react-router-dom library.
This is my fragment with Browser Router

```
<BrowserRouter history={history}>
  <Main />
</BrowserRouter >
```

And here is fragment of my main component

```
 <Switch>
    {!user ? (
      <>
        <Route
          path="/login"
          exact
          component={() => (
            <LoginView login={login} loginError={loginError} />
          )}
        />
      </>
    ) : (
      routes.map((route, id) => (
        <Route
          key={id}
          path={route.path ?? null}
          exact={route.exact ? true : false}
          component={() => (
            <>
              <AppTopBar logout={logout} />

              <div className={classes.mainContainer}>
                <route.component logout={logout} user={user} />
              </div>

              <AppFooter />
            </>
          )}
        />
      ))
    )}
  </Switch>
```

So basically I check if user exists if yes it goes to first Home page if not it goes to Login page.
Everything works fine on localhost. The problem happens when I upload app on github pages. When I go to `https://username.github.io/appname` it opens fine. When I click on button to go to a new page it changes URL to for example `https://username.github.io/newItem` or `https://username.github.io/items` but it still works. The problem is when I reload the page I get:

[image]

What is the best way to use router in react component that needs to be deployed on github pages or any other place? How should I create routes for it so it works all the time? My routes looks like this:

```
 const routes = [
      {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: HomeView,
        exact: true,
      }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Pages doesn't support `BrowserRouter`:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing

So you will need to explore alternatives. Here is a helpful answer about using HashRouter instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024739

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhere solution like that:

```
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Main />
    </Router>
```

So I add line:
`"homepage": "https://username.github.io/appname"`

in `package.json` file

and it works well, I can go to `https://username.github.io/appname` and move through all app without problem but when I reload the page I immediately get the same error:

[image]